# Are the these mathematical symbols considered predicate symbols or function symbols?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Using the definition of that  "a ***predicate*** is a function that returns true or false, that might not be computable" and "a ***function*** is a predicate that returns object."

Is my classification of the following mathematical symbols correct?

**∩** (intersection) is a function symbol because it returns an object, the intersection between two sets.

**⊆** (subset) is a predicate symbol that returns true if the subset has fewer elements or equal to the set.

**0** (zero) is a function symbol since it is a constant symbol? (I'm not sure of this explanation).

**=** (equals) is binary predicate symbol.

Comment: Everything looks fine.

Comment: Although those definitions are goofy.

Comment: ...and the description of "subset" is completely wrong, although "subset" is indeed a predicate...

Comment: @JohnHughes Ok understood, is this definition acceptable? Every element of the subset is also a member of the other set?

Comment: @PetarKool *That's* correct.

Comment: But to have two definitions that say : "a *predicate* is a function that..." and "a *function* is a predicate that ..." looks circular. Maybe we can start with *function* : "a 'something' that for each input returns a single value as output" and then define *predicate* as a function that has only two possible values : True and False.

Comment: Indeed.  All ducks are birds (with certain features), but not all birds are ducks.